# custom module for filtering products in prestashop

Tags: php, sql, prestashop-1.6

Hi I am totally new to prestashop and I working on building a module for filtering based on the rating of the products. I have build a module and have some how able to make a ajax request to get the product based on the rating.
But my real issue is how can I list the product that I receive in the front end ? I know listing is done with help of smarty

My module file function for getting products

```
public function ajaxProcessMyAjaxMethod($ratings)
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM "._DB_PREFIX_."product WHERE ";
    $sql .= " ratingone=$ratings[0] OR";
    $sql .= " ratingtwo=$ratings[1] OR";
    $sql .= " ratingthree=$ratings[2]";

    $row = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);
    return $row;
}
```

The above file is for getting the products based on the ratings.I don't even know for sure if its correct or not, anyways it serves the purpose.

I get an array of products but I am not sure what is the next step. I have gone through couple of tutorials online but they are not upto my requirements.

"Now I want to show the products as they are shown by layered module of prestashop but based on rating and not on size etc."

Note: I have three different types of rating for the same products.

If anyone can guide me with link to any tutorial or providing me with some examples it would be helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let me tell you that you should replace the function for fetching products with proper a function that return products in proper limits as it will help you in adding pagination on the product listing page.

In order to list the products, you should assign the products array to smarty and then fetch the product-list.tpl file in your theme's directory, using the following code:

```
$this->context->smarty->fetch(_PS_THEME_DIR_.'product-list.tpl');
```

Hope this helps you in solving your problem.